# iOS IAP subscriptions/App Store Server to Server Notifications. Replacing the verifyReceipt API with unified_receipt

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm in the process of upgrading an existing iOS IAP subscription system that already makes use of App Store Server Notifications. My existing solution is using the now deprecated `latest_receipt`, `latest_receipt_info`, `latest_expired_receipt` and `latest_expired_receipt_info` fields. According to Apple, these fields are now all replaced with the single [`unified_receipt`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/notification_type) field.

After watching all the required WWDC videos and sifting through the little documentation available I'm still left with a few unanswered questions.

The `latest_receipt_info` field is documented as:

> An array that contains the latest 100 in-app purchase transactions of the decoded value in latest_receipt.

This means that this array will contain the customer's entire transaction history. This will not only include the relevant subscription but also any transactional products the customer may have purchased.

My question here is how can I find the relevant transaction in this array? The relevant transaction in this case would be the one that [triggered the event](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/notification_type) (e.g. `CANCEL`). I need this transaction in order to update our backend database to reflect the current subscription status. For example, to update the subscription end date to the [`cancellation_date`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/pending_renewal_info) on a `CANCEL` event .

I have a similar question regarding the [`pending_renewal_info`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/pending_renewal_info) array. It's unclear to me from the existing documentation if all customers with an active (or maybe even expired?) subscription will always have an entry in this array.

> An array of elements that refers to auto-renewable subscription renewals that are open or failed in the past.

I also need to find the relevant transaction in this field to do things like toggle the subscription status on a `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` event or update the billing status on a `DID_FAIL_TO_RENEW` event. From the docs it doesn't look like there is enough info in the `pending_renewal_info` alone to compute the current subscription renewal status.

**Overall my question really boils down to:**

Can I be sure that there will be an entry in both `unified_receipt.latest_receipt_info` and `unified_receipt.pending_renewal_info` that matches the top level event `auto_renew_product_id`? And if so how should I find the relevant object in the respective array? Will there only be a single entry for each `auto_renew_product_id` or should I search the array and pull out the first match?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the transactions inside `unified_receipt.latest_receipt_info` array are ordered by purchased date from the latest to the oldest. And sure that you can found out the the top level event `auto_renew_product_id`.

However, for updating the subscription status or billing status, I utilize the return value from `/verifyRecipt`, which you can get by requesting to the Apple verifyReceipt server with receipt-data and password(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt).  Noted that the input receipt-data is `unified_receipt.latest_receipt`, and the responses share the same structure as `unified_receipt`.